# MVC Web Api and SQL Server views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for some links to blog posts or something to that effect related to using SQL Server views with MVC web api. Seemingly, searching for this on google does not bear any fruit.

Thank you

Comment: Anything more specific than that? Selecting from a view is tantamount to selecting from a table. What sort of data access strategy were you looking at? Object Relational Mapper, SQL Client etc.?

Comment: Using EF for my ORM. So I just code it as if the name of the view is the name of a SQL table?

Comment: Try this for info: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1990/how-to-use-sql-server-views-with-the-entity-framework/  And this might also be helpful: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/